# website detects that I'm using requests - python

Tags: python, html, http, python-requests, proxies

I'm trying to register an account via python requests.

```
> headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1;
> en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.27
> Safari/525.13', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Host': 'www.google.com',
> 'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/', 'DNT': '1' } 
> r =
> requests.get(url, headers = headers)
> 
> html = r.text
> 
> hidden = True if "g-recaptcha-response" in html:
> hidden = False
> 
> print(hidden)
```

However, every time I try, the captcha is excluded.
When I access the website via browser, the captcha is contained in HTML.

What can I do ?

Also, when using a proxy via browser, captcha is also excluded.
The websites seems to have a 'seriousity-detection system', that block any not fully regular basic browser connection.

I'm very thankful for help.

Comment: Perhaps the captcha is created dynamically through Javascript.  `requests` doesn't execute Javascript.

Comment: Try making your request legit by including with cookies and making few visits